# Heatmap not working on FeatureLayer (ArcGIS JS API 4.8)

Tags: feature-layer, heat-map, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, rendering

I tried my best but didn't get success to show heatmap on FeatureLayer with latest ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.8. My Code is located [here](https://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthMishra/eLg10whk/).
I used [HeatMapRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-HeatmapRenderer.html) to render the point on the map as the heat map. But somehow it is not working at all. I think I am missing something which would be an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HeatmapRenderer only works with WebGL-enabled FeatureLayer, and at version 4.8 one of the limitations for WebGL-support is listed as:

- `Layers created from feature collections or client-side graphics are not supported.` https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#webgl-rendering

This limitation should hopefully go away at next release (version 4.9).